# PG fulltext search: Boost factor for word in the title

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I use PostgreSQL full text search and it works fine.

The database schema is simple. A page has a title and a content.

Up to now I just index the string which I get by joining title+content.

In the future I would like to adapt the ranking. If a search term is in the title
of a document, then I would like to rank this page higher.

How can I influence the search ranking in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that using [`ts_rank`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING):

You can use `setweight` to give different parts of the text search vector different weight:

```
SELECT * from atable
WHERE (to_tsvector('english', title) ||
       to_tsvector('english', content)
      ) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'happy <-> home')
ORDER BY ts_rank(setweight(to_tsvector('english', title), 'A') ||
                 setweight(to_tsvector('english', content), 'C'),
                 to_tsquery('english', 'happy <-> home'));
```

Then the `title` will be ranked higher (weight `A`) than the `content` (weight `C`).